# awk to print Consecutive Sequential Numbers -Start Sequence and End Sequence:

Tags: awk

Would like to print Consecutive Sequential Numbers -Start Sequence and End Sequence from First Field, And the combinations of $2,substr($3,1,9),substr($4,4,6),$6,$8,$10 fields.
Input file is not sorted as per first column.

Input.txt

```
11,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
12,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
13,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
14,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29
28,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29
32,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30
33,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30
41,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
50,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
51,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
52,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
```

Have tried this command for first field only and got the partial output:

```
cat Input.txt | sort -k1 -t,| awk -F, 'NR==1 {a=$1;b=$1;next} ($1 != b+1){print a,"-",b; a=$1} {b=$1} END{print a,"-",b}'

11 - 14
28 - 28
32 - 33
41 - 41
50 - 52
```

Desired Output:

### $2,$3,$4,$6,$8,$10,Start_No,End_No

```
abc,22-JUN-12,JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,11,13
abc,30-JUN-12,JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,14,14
abc,30-JUN-12,JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,28,28
def,29-MAY-13,MAY-13,1350,RO0213,K1,32,33
abc,20-FEB-14,FEB-14,650,EN1113,S317,41,41
abc,20-FEB-14,FEB-14,650,EN1113,S317,50,52
```

Edit: Update SampleInput.txt without in sort order, Ed Morton you are correct , my actual input file is not in sort order , would like know how to candle the below sample.

```
13,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
14,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29
11,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
12,abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,31
28,abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,19-Apr-16,1,INR,RO0412,RC03,L7,,29
32,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30
33,def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,15-Feb-17,1350,INR,RO0213,CD,K1,,30
41,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
50,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
52,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
51,abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,31-Dec-20,650,INR,EN1113,ch650,S317,,28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
    seq = $1
    key = $2 FS substr($3,1,9) FS substr($4,4,6) FS $6 FS $8 FS $10

    if ( (seq != (prevSeq+1)) || (key != prevKey) ) {
        if (startSeq != "")
            print prevKey, startSeq, prevSeq
        startSeq = seq
    }

    prevSeq = seq
    prevKey = key
}
END {
    print key, startSeq, prevSeq
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
abc,22-JUN-12,JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,11,13
abc,30-JUN-12,JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,14,14
abc,30-JUN-12,JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,28,28
def,29-MAY-13,MAY-13,1350,RO0213,K1,32,33
abc,20-FEB-14,FEB-14,650,EN1113,S317,41,41
abc,20-FEB-14,FEB-14,650,EN1113,S317,50,52
```

Comment: Ed Morton , since the Input.txt is not sorted , tried this command sort -k1 -t, file.txt | awk -f tst.awk file.txt but it is not working

Comment: Tried like this : awk -f tst.awk (sort -k1 -t, file.txt) also not working , please suggest

Comment: The input doesn't need to be sorted, just grouped by the key fields (`$2,substr($3,1,9),substr($4,4,6),$6,$8,$10`) like your posted sample input. Just stating `it is not working` doesn't provide any information for anyone to help you debug it but the most likely problem is that your real input doesn't follow the same pattern of key fields being grouped as your posted sample input - if that's the case, edit your question to show some input that better represents your real input.

Comment: Ed Morton, you are correct, please refer Edit Sample file without sort order now, earlier actually i have pasted sorted input to undersatnd the question easily, please advise !!!

Answer (score 2):

A script like this may do. I hope someone doesn't just do a condensed version of it:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
{
    # sub(/[.].*$/, "", $3)  ## Uncomment if you don't want to include the time.
    # sub(/[.].*$/, "", $4)  ## Uncomment if you don't want to include the time.
    key = $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $6 "," $8 "," $10
    if (!(key in s)) {
        s[key] = e[key] = $1
        keys[k++] = key
    } else if ($1 < s[key]) {
        s[key] = $1
    } else if ($1 > e[key]) {
        e[key] = $1
    }
}
END {
    for (k = 0; k in keys; ++k) {
        key = keys[k]
        print key, s[key], e[key]
    }
}
```

And perhaps similar:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
{
    # sub(/[.].*$/, "", $3)
    # sub(/[.].*$/, "", $4)
    key = $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $6 "," $8 "," $10
}
!s[key] {
    s[key] = e[key] = $1
    keys[k++] = key
    next
}
$1 < s[key] {
    s[key] = $1
    next  ## Optional.
}
$1 > e[key] {
    e[key] = $1
}
END {
    for (k = 0; k in keys; ++k) {
        key = keys[k]
        print key, s[key], e[key]
    }
}
```

With

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Outputs:

```
abc,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,22-JUN-12.08:06:03,1,RO0412,L7,11,13
abc,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,30-JUN-12.01:06:49,1,RO0412,L7,14,28
def,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,29-MAY-13.12:05:11,1350,RO0213,K1,32,33
abc,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,20-FEB-14.11:02:37,650,EN1113,S317,41,52
```

Output that excludes the time (Uncomment the `sub()` lines):

```
abc,22-JUN-12,22-JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,11,13
abc,30-JUN-12,30-JUN-12,1,RO0412,L7,14,28
def,29-MAY-13,29-MAY-13,1350,RO0213,K1,32,33
abc,20-FEB-14,20-FEB-14,650,EN1113,S317,41,52
```

Comment: @AVN It's bad that I didn't read well what you wanted there but no worries you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this generates the output you want (identical to what you've displayed).

```
sort -k1 -t, Input.txt |
awk '
  function prn() {print f2,d1,substr(f4,1,6),f6,f8,f10,n1,n2}
  function sav() {n1=$1;d1=d;f2=$2;f4=$4;f6=$6;f8=$8;f10=$10}
  BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
  {d = substr($3,1,9)}
  NR == 1 {sav(); n2=n1; d2=d1; next}
  $1 != n2 + 1 || d1 != d {prn(); sav()}
  {n2=$1; d2=d}
  END {prn()}
'
```

I made the assumption that you actually want the *first* 6 chars of field 4 (the day and month) instead of the last 6 (month and year).